# Driver for Ensoniq AudioPCI ES1370 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sound-card, linux-kvm

[KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) is a virtualisation package for running operating systems such as Windows on Linux. Windows XP works fine in this, but Windows 7 fails to recognise the sound card. According to the documentation, the soundcard is a Ensoniq AudioPCI ES1370. Does anyone know where I can find a driver for this, or a compatible driver that will run under 7.

I've not tried this in Vista as yet.

Comment: Simply try using VirtualBox, or VMWare Player / Workstation. (Player is totally free and can create images/configs also.)

Answer (score 2):

I have filed the same bug in ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kvm/+bug/419182

Short answer: windows7 has no builtin driver for es1370.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly true since the driver is autodetected and working in Windows 7 32-bit. I believe there is no 64-bit driver for this sound card as even on the creative site there is no driver for xp / vista in 64bit.